# How to check that all types in variadic template are convertible to size_t?

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates, implicit-conversion

How can I check that all types in a variadic template declaration can be converted to size_t:

```
// instantiate only if extents params are all convertible to size_t
template<typename T, size_t N>
template<typename... E>
Array<T,N>::Array(E... extents) {
    constexpr size_t n = sizeof...(extents);
    static_assert(n == N, "Dimensions do not match");
    // code for handling variadic template parameters corresponding to dimension sizes
}
```

With the following usage:

```
Array<double, 2> a(5,6);    // OK 2-D array of 5*6 values of doubles.
Array<int, 3> a(2,10,15)    // OK 3-D array of 2*10*15 values of int.
Array<int, 2> a(2, "d")     // Error: "d" is not a valid dimension and cannot be implicitly converted to size_t
```

Here are similar questions:
[Check for arguments type in a variadic template declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20045617/check-for-arguments-type-in-a-variadic-template-declaration)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With help from the really slick `all_true` trick from [Columbo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28253399/check-traits-for-all-variadic-template-arguments/28253503#28253503), it's a breeze :

```
template <bool...> struct bool_pack;
template <bool... v>
using all_true = std::is_same<bool_pack<true, v...>, bool_pack<v..., true>>;

template <class... Args>
std::enable_if_t<
    all_true<std::is_convertible<Args, std::size_t>{}...>{}
> check(Args... args) {}
```

[Live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6a6542aa2ccd509e)

And in the specific case where Check is a constructor:

```
template<typename... Args, class = std::enable_if_t<all_true<std::is_convertible<Args, std::size_t>{}...>{}>>
    explicit Check(Args... args) {}
```

Comment: Could someone also please explain the logic behind the Columbo's "trick"? Thanks!

Comment: @BigLudinski Basically, all the booleans of a sequence `S` are true *iff* `[true, S] == [S, true]`. I only grasped it when trying it on a piece of paper though.

Comment: thanks for the update. One last question: how should I adapt the template if I need to check for an exact match (i.e. that all the args are of type size_t exactly. For example I would not want the user to pass a character as an argument, which is convertible)

Comment: @BigLudinski well, just replace `is_convertible` with `is_same` :)