# C++ variadic template arguments method to pass to a method without variadic arguments

Tags: c++, function, loops, templates, variadic-templates

I have the following question, I really can't compile from all the questions and articles researched:

In C++, is it possible to have a method with variadic template arguments that specify types of arguments (as a meta-description type for parameters of in, out, in/out of a certain type, to be passed by value, by address etc.), to loop through these variadic arguments in order to instantiate variables of specified types, and be passed these variables to functions specified by a pointer in a template parameter, but these functions not having variadic parameters?

**EDIT 1**

I try here to detail, as *pseudocode*:

```
template <decltype(*Type::*Method), typename... Parameters>
static bool ExecuteMethod(JSContext *cx, unsigned argc, JS::Value *vp)
{
    JS::CallArgs args = CallArgsFromVp(argc, vp);

    loop through Parameters
    {
        Parameters[i]::Type p[i] <-- args[i];
    }

    ReturnType r = Method(p[0], p[1], p[2] .. p[n]); // the method does not have variadic parameters
...
}
```

where Method might be like:

```
int(*GetColor) ( int16 *color);
int(*GetFile) ( FilePath &file );
int(*WriteDocument) ( const FilePath &file, const char *fileFormatName, bool askForParms);
```

etc.

This comes out of wrapping needs.
The challenge is something missing in C++, reflection as in .net.
It is possible to instance an array of heterogeneous objects by looping through the variadic arguments somehow? Probably.
But how pass them to methods having no variadic arguments? I think it is not possible to assign that array of objects to functions like these three above without explicit wrappers, isn't it?

**EDIT 2**

I've got a lot of feed-back, but it is clear I was not specific enough.
I did not detailed too much because I've got complains in the past for being too specific. Indeed, I do not have easy implementations and I am a generic guy, not lazy, but I try to make a latter development faster.

Here is the source of the problem: I need to wrap Adobe Illustrator API, which exposes hundreds if not thousands of pointers to functions grouped in structs, called *suites*.

I try to have a javascript engine using SpiderMonkey.

I use Visual Studio 2015 compiler.

My approach is as follows:

I have several classes to wrap the API in order to add to SpiderMonkey's engine objects for all the suites. Each SpiderMonkey class, could be called as *jsData*, wraps a data type of Adobe SDK, or a suite, *jsSuite*.

So far, I have used templates because SpiderMonkey forces me to add each function to its custom objects with a specific signature, like this:

```
bool jsAIDocumentSuite::WriteDocument(JSContext *cx, unsigned argc, JS::Value *vp)
{
...
}
```

and adding it to the custom object would be done like this:

```
const JSFunctionSpec jsAIDocumentSuite::fFunctions[] = {
...
    JS_FN("WriteDocument", jsAIDocumentSuite::WriteDocument, 3, 0),
...
}
```

JS_FN is a SpiderMonkeyMacro.

Actually, this is, so far, less than 10% of the Adobe SDK.

The most are getters and setters with one parameter, passed by value or address or pointer, so I have replaced them by a generic function, like this:

```
    template <typename jsType, typename jsReturnType, typename ReturnPrivateType = jsReturnType::PrivateType, typename jsParamType, typename ParamPrivateType = jsParamType::PrivateType, ReturnPrivateType(*Type::*Method)(ParamPrivateType&)>
    static bool GetByRefMethod(JSContext *cx, unsigned argc, JS::Value *vp)
    {
        JS::CallArgs args = CallArgsFromVp(argc, vp);

        try
        {
            ReturnPrivateType result;

            ParamPrivateType ppt;

            if (jsType::Suite() && (jsType::Suite()->*Method))
                result = (jsType::Suite()->*Method)(ppt);
            else
                return false; // TODO throw a meaningful error

            if ((jsReturnType::IsNoError(result)) && (argc > 0) && (args[0].isObject()))
            {
                JSObject *obj = &args[0].toObject();

                JSObject *value = NULL;
                if (!jsParamType::FromAIObject<jsParamType>(cx, &ppt, value))
                    return false;

                if (!value)
                    return false;

                jsProperty::SetProperty(cx, &obj, "value", value, true);
            }

            JSObject *obj = JS_NewObject(cx, &jsDataClass<jsReturnType>::fClass);

            JS_SetPrivate(obj, new ReturnPrivateType(result));

            args.rval().setObject(*obj);
        }
        EXCEPTION_CATCH_CONVERT();

        return true;
    }
```

A bit complicated, isn't it?

What is relevant, above, is:

- The *args* variable holds the SpiderMonkey parameters passed in by its engine
- Only one argument is passed here, *ppt*
- The return type is one value, so it is easy to be handled

I use macros to inject the method in its variants (several short forms too, not so interesting here):

```
JS_FN(#GET_METHOD, (js##TYPE::GetByRefMethod<js##TYPE, RETURN_JS_TYPE, RETURN_PRIVATE_TYPE, PARAM_JS_TYPE, PARAM_PRIVATE_TYPE, &TYPE::GET_METHOD>), 1, 0)
```

I wish to be able to handle variable arguments, according to the statistics more philosophical, but interesting. The idea would be opposite to the C++, probably, and not as expected.

How would I expect it:

I wish to add variadic parameters meta-information, like:

template 
        static bool Method(JSContext *cx, unsigned argc, JS::Value *vp)
        {
            JS::CallArgs args = CallArgsFromVp(argc, vp);

```
        try
        {
            ReturnPrivateType result;

            *1st challenge: Loop through the variadic list of meta-parameters and create their corresponding object instances here and initialize the IN ones with values from the *args* collection passed by the SpiderMonkey engine*

            if (jsType::Suite() && (jsType::Suite()->*Method))
                result = (jsType::Suite()->*Method)(*2nd challenge: pass arguments here: probably by using a variadic macro?*);
            else
                return false; // TODO throw a meaningful error

            if ((jsReturnType::IsNoError(result)) && (argc > 0) && (args[0].isObject()))
            {
                JSObject *obj = &args[0].toObject();

                JSObject *value = NULL;
                if (!jsParamType::FromAIObject<jsParamType>(cx, &ppt, value))
                    return false;

                if (!value)
                    return false;

                jsProperty::SetProperty(cx, &obj, "value", value, true);
            }

            JSObject *obj = JS_NewObject(cx, &jsDataClass<jsReturnType>::fClass);

            JS_SetPrivate(obj, new ReturnPrivateType(result));

            args.rval().setObject(*obj);
        }
        EXCEPTION_CATCH_CONVERT();

        return true;
    }
```

As you can see, it is not as C++ expected, it is a bit reversed, by trying to avoid writing templates to deduct the parameters, here, I know the parameters first and try to write a code to generate the right parameters by knowing their meta-information first and I have a clear set of types and I *promise* to write the right code to generate the correct wrappers. I don't need to validate much regarding the data of the parameters, as things are mostly passed without a huge business logic in the process.

**EDIT 3**

About the parameters meta-information, I could write a few types with statics to specify the data type of the parameter, whether it is a return type, whether it is an IN, an OUT or an IN/OUT parameter, its *jsType* etc..
They would be the variadic list of the template parameters function above.

Comment: instead of describing, why don't provide a minimal code example

Comment: god, that was a long hard to follow phrase. Felt like a marathon. Split it into sentences, ideas. And yes it is far better to show some code then to describe code.

Comment: The best you could do is to create a std::tuple containing the arbitrary number of template arguments, then feed that into a template method which takes a generic std::tuple as its non-variadic argument. At least, I think that works. I will clarify that in a minute.

Comment: You cannot instantiate a "pack of variables" in current C++, though you can instantiate a tuple, which is often close enough.

Comment: Sorry for the complicated sentence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Continued from part 1: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35109026/5386374 ]

---

There is an issue, however.  We had to change the way our code is written to accomodate `ExecuteMethod()`, which may not always be possible.  Is there a way around that, so that it functions exactly the same as your previously specified `ExecuteMethod()`, and doesn't need to take the variable it modifies as a macro parameter?  The answer is... yes!

```
// Variadic function-like macro to automatically create, use, and destroy functor.
// Uncomment whichever one is appropriate for the compiler used.
//  (The difference being that Visual C++ automatically removes the trailing comma if the
//   macro has zero variadic arguments, while GCC needs a hint in the form of "##" to tell
//   it to do so.)
// Instead of a do...while structure, we can just use a temporary Executor directly.
// MSVC:
// #define ExecuteMethod(M, ...) Executor<decltype(&M), decltype(&M)>{}(M, __VA_ARGS__)
// GCC:
#define ExecuteMethod(M, ...) Executor<decltype(&M), decltype(&M)>{}(M, ##__VA_ARGS__)

// For your example function WriteDocument(), defined as
//   int WriteDocument(const FilePath &file, const char *fileFormatName, bool askForParms);

bool c = ExecuteMethod(WriteDocument, file, fileFormatName, askForParams);
```

This is all well and good, but there is one more change we can make to simplify things without impacting performance.  At the moment, this functor can only take function pointers (and maybe lambdas, I'm not familiar with their syntax), not other types of function objects.  If this is intended, it means that we can rewrite it to do away with the first template parameter (the entire signature), since the second and third parameters are themselves components of the signature.

```
// Default functor.
template<typename... Ts>
struct Executor { };

// General case.
template<typename ReturnType, typename... Params>
struct Executor<ReturnType (*)(Params...)> {
    private:
        // Instead of explicitly taking M as a parameter, create it from
        //  the other parameters.
        using M = ReturnType (*)(Params...);
    public:
        // Parameter match:
        bool operator()(M method, Params... params) {
            ReturnType r = method(params...);
            // ...
        }

        // Parameter mismatch:
        template<typename... Invalid_Params>
        bool operator()(M method, Invalid_Params... ts) {
            // Handle parameter type mismatch here.
        }
};

// Special case to catch void return type.
template<typename... Params>
struct Executor<void (*)(Params...)> {
    private:
        // Instead of explicitly taking M as a parameter, create it from
        //  the other parameters.
        using M = void (*)(Params...);
    public:
        // Parameter match:
        bool operator()(M method, Params... params) {
            method(params...);
            // ...
        }

        // Parameter mismatch:
        template<typename... Invalid_Params>
        bool operator()(M method, Invalid_Params... ts) {
            // Handle parameter type mismatch here.
        }
};

// Variadic function-like macro to automatically create, use, and destroy functor.
// Uncomment whichever one is appropriate for the compiler used.
//  (The difference being that Visual C++ automatically removes the trailing comma if the
//   macro has zero variadic arguments, while GCC needs a hint in the form of "##" to tell
//   it to do so.)
// Instead of a do...while structure, we can just use a temporary Executor directly.
// MSVC:
// #define ExecuteMethod(M, ...) Executor<decltype(&M)>{}(M, __VA_ARGS__)
// GCC:
#define ExecuteMethod(M, ...) Executor<decltype(&M)>{}(M, ##__VA_ARGS__)


// Note: If your compiler doesn't support C++11 "using" type aliases, replace them
//       with the following:
//           typedef ReturnType (*M)(Params...);
```

This results in cleaner code, but, as mentioned, limits the functor to only accepting function pointers.

When used like this, the functor expects parameters to be an exact match.  It can handle reference-ness and cv-ness correctly, but may have issues with rvalues, I'm not sure.  See [here](http://ideone.com/IE27rR).

As to how to use this with your `JSContext`... I'm honestly not sure.  I haven't learned about contexts yet, so someone else would be more helpful for that.  I would suggest checking if one of the other answers here would be more useful in your situation, in all honesty.

---

Note: I'm not sure how easy it would be to modify the functor to work if its function parameter is a functor, lambda, `std::function`, or anything of the sort.

---

Note 2: As before, I'm not sure if there would be any negative effects on performance for doing something like this.  There's likely a more efficient way, but I don't know what it would be.

Answer (score 2):

I still am having some difficulty understanding exactly what you want to do, but this should let you call a function(without variardic parameters) using a variardic template function, getting the parameters from an array and allowing a conversion operation to apply to each parameter before being passed to the function:

```
    #include <functional>

    template<typename T, typename JST> T getParam(const JST& a)
    {
        //Do whatever conversion necessary
        return a;
    }
    namespace detail
    {
        template<typename R, typename... Args, int... S> R jsCaller(std::function<R(Args...)> f, seq<S...>, const JS::CallArgs& args)
        {
            return f(getParam<Args, /*Whatever type should go here */>(args[S])...);
        }
    }
    //Actually use this to call the function and get the result
    template<typename R, typename... Args> R jsCall(std::function<R(Args...)> f, const JS::CallArgs& args)
    {
        return detail::jsCaller(f, GenSequence<sizeof...(Args)>(), args);
    }
```

Where GenSequence extends seq<0, 1, 2, ... , N - 1> and can be implemented as follows:

```
template<int... N>
struct seq {};

template<int N, int... S>
struct gens : gens<N-1, N-1, S...> {};

template<int... S>
struct gens<0, S...> 
{
    typedef seq<S...> type;
};

template<int N> using GenSequence<N> = typename gens<N>::type;
```

This creates a parameter pack of integers, and expands the function call using them- See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7858817/unpacking-a-tuple-to-call-a-matching-function-pointer) question.

You can call your method using jsCall:

```
Result r = jsCall((Method), args);
```

Assuming Method can be converted to std::function- if not, you can still do it by making a lambda which conforms to std::function. Does this solve the problem?

Comment: Thanks, this is very close of what I need.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with the following C++11 solution, which gives the basic idea. It could very easily be improved, however, so I welcome suggestions. [Live test here](https://ideone.com/8uGGOs).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
using namespace std;

// bar : does something with an arbitrary tuple
// (no variadic template arguments)
template <class Tuple>
void bar(Tuple t)
{
    // .... do something with the tuple ...
    std::cout << std::tuple_size<Tuple>::value;
}

// foo : takes a function pointer and an arbitrary number of other
// arguments
template <class Func, typename... Ts>
void foo(Func f, Ts... args_in)
{
    // construct a tuple containing the variadic arguments
    std::tuple<Ts...> t = std::make_tuple(args_in...);

    // pass this tuple to the function f
    f(t);
}

int main()
{
    // this is not highly refined; you must provide the types of the
    // arguments (any suggestions?)
    foo(bar<std::tuple<int, const char *, double>>, 123, "foobar", 43.262);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Edit: After seeing your "Edit 2", I don't believe this is the proper solution.  Leaving it up for reference, though.

I believe I've found a potential solution that catches reference-ness, too.  Scroll down to the bottom, to the "Edit 4" section.

---

If you're asking whether it's possible to dynamically check template argument types, you can.  I'll start with a general example of how to use `std::true_type` and `std::false_type` to overload based on whether a specified condition is met, then move on to your problem specifically.  Consider this:

```
#include <type_traits>

namespace SameComparison {
    // Credit for the contents of this namespace goes to dyp ( https://stackoverflow.com/a/20047561/5386374 )
    template<class T, class...> struct are_same : std::true_type{};

    template<class T, class U, class... TT> struct are_same<T, U, TT...> :
        std::integral_constant<bool, std::is_same<T, U>{} && are_same<T, TT...>{} >{};
} // namespace SameComparison

template<typename T> class SomeClass {
    public:
        SomeClass() = default;
        template<typename... Ts> SomeClass(T arg1, Ts... args);
        ~SomeClass() = default;

        void func(T arg1);
        template<typename U> void func(U arg1);
        template<typename... Ts> void func(T arg1, Ts... args);
        template<typename U, typename... Ts> void func(U arg1, Ts... args);

        // ...

    private:
        template<typename... Ts> SomeClass(std::true_type x, T arg1, Ts... args);
        template<typename... Ts> SomeClass(std::false_type x, T arg1, Ts... args);

        // ...
};

// Constructors:
// -------------
// Public multi-argument constructor.
// Passes to one of two private constructors, depending on whether all types in paramater pack match T.
template<typename T> template<typename... Ts> SomeClass<T>::SomeClass(T arg1, Ts... args) :
    SomeClass(SameComparison::are_same<T, Ts...>{}, arg1, args...) { }

// All arguments match.
template<typename T> template<typename... Ts> SomeClass<T>::SomeClass(std::true_type x, T arg1, Ts... args) { }

// One or more arguments is incorrect type.
template<typename T> template<typename... Ts> SomeClass<T>::SomeClass(std::false_type x, T arg1, Ts... args) {
    static_assert(x.value, "Arguments wrong type.");
}

/*
Note that if you don't need to use Ts... in the parameter list, you can combine the previous two into a single constructor:

template<typename T> template<bool N, typename... Ts> SomeClass<T>::SomeClass(std::integral_constant<bool, N> x, T arg1, Ts... args) {
    static_assert(x.value, "Arguments wrong type.");
}

x will be true_type (value == true) on type match, or false_type (value == false) on type mismatch.  Haven't thoroughly tested this, just ran a similar function through an online compiler to make sure it could determine N.
*/

// Member functions:
// -----------------
// Single argument, type match.
template<typename T> void SomeClass<T>::func(T arg1) {
    // code
}

// Single argument, type mismatch.
// Also catches true_type from multi-argument functions after they empty their parameter pack, and silently ignores it.
template<typename T> template<typename U> void SomeClass<T>::func(U arg1) {
    if (arg1 != std::true_type{}) {
        std::cout << "Argument " << arg1 << " wrong type." << std::endl;
    }
}

// Multiple arguments, argument 1 type match.
template<typename T> template<typename... Ts> void SomeClass<T>::func(T arg1, Ts... args) {
    func(arg1);
    func(args...);
//  func(SameComparison::are_same<T, Ts...>{}, vals...);
}

// Multiple arguments, argument 1 type mismatch.
template<typename T> template<typename U, typename... Ts> void SomeClass<T>::func(U arg1, Ts... args) {
//  if (arg1 != std::true_type{}) {
//      std::cout << "Argument " << arg1 << " wrong type." << std::endl;
//  }
    func(vals...);
}
```

First, `SameComparison::are_same` there is an extension of `std::is_same`, that applies it to an entire parameter pack.  This is the basis of the check, with the rest of the example showing how it can be used.  The lines commented out of the last two functions show how it could be applied there, as well.

---

Now, onto your problem specifically.  Since you know what the methods are, you can make similar comparison structs for them.

```
int (*GetColor) ( int16_t *color);
int(*GetFile) ( FilePath &file );
int(*WriteDocument) ( const FilePath &file, const char *fileFormatName, bool askForParms);
```

Could have...

```
namespace ParameterCheck {
    template<typename T, typename... Ts> struct parameter_match : public std::false_type {};

    // Declare (GetColor, int16_t*) valid.
    template<> struct parameter_match<int (*)(int16_t*), int16_t*> : public std::true_type {};

    // Declare (GetFile, FilePath&) valid.
    // template<> struct parameter_match<int (*)(FilePath&), FilePath&> : public std::true_type {}; // You'd think this would work, but...
    template<> struct parameter_match<int (*)(FilePath&), FilePath> : public std::true_type {}; // Nope!
    // For some reason, reference-ness isn't part of the templated type.  It acts as if it was "template<typename T> void func(T& arg)" instead.

    // Declare (WriteDocument, const FilePath&, const char*, bool) valid.
    // template<> struct parameter_match<int (*)(const FilePath&, const char*, bool), const FilePath, const char*, bool> : public std::true_type {};
    // template<> struct parameter_match<int (*)(const FilePath&, const char*, bool), const FilePath&, const char*, bool> : public std::true_type {};
    template<> struct parameter_match<int (*)(const FilePath&, const char*, bool), FilePath, const char*, bool> : public std::true_type {};
    // More reference-as-template-parameter wonkiness: Out of these three, only the last works.
} // namespace ParameterCheck
```

Here, we make a general-case struct that equates to `std::false_type`, then specialise it so that specific cases are `true_type` instead.  What this does is tell the compiler, "These parameter lists are good, anything else is bad," where each list starts with a function pointer and ends with the arguments to the function.  Then, you can do something like this for your caller:

```
// The actual calling function.
template<typename Func, typename... Ts> void caller2(std::true_type x, Func f, Ts... args) {
    std::cout << "Now calling... ";
    f(args...);
}

// Parameter mismatch overload.
template<typename Func, typename... Ts> void caller2(std::false_type x, Func f, Ts... args) {
    std::cout << "Parameter list mismatch." << std::endl;
}

// Wrapper to check for parameter mismatch.
template<typename Func, typename... Ts> void caller(Func f, Ts... args) {
    caller2(ParameterCheck::parameter_match<Func, Ts...>{}, f, args...);
}
```

As for return type deduction... that depends on where you want to deduce it:

- Determine variable type from contents: Use `auto` when declaring the variable.
- Determine return type from passed function return type: If your compiler is C++14-compatible, that's easy.  Just use `auto`.  [VStudio 2015 and GCC 4.8.0 (with `-std=c++1y`) are compatible with `auto` return type.]

The former can be done like this:

```
int i = 42;
int func1() { return 23; }
char func2() { return 'c'; }
float func3() { return -0.0f; }

auto a0 = i; // a0 is int.
auto a1 = func1(); // a1 is int.
auto a2 = func2(); // a2 is char.
auto a3 = func3(); // a3 is float.
```

The latter, however, is more complex.

```
std::string stringMaker() {
    return std::string("Here, have a string!");
}

int intMaker() {
    return 5;
}

template<typename F> auto automised(F f) {
    return f();
}

// ...

auto a = automised(stringMaker); // a is std::string.
auto b = automised(intMaker);    // a is int.
```

If your compiler isn't compatible with `auto` or `decltype(auto)` return type... well, it's a bit more verbose, but we can do this:

```
namespace ReturnTypeCapture {
    // Credit goes to Angew ( https://stackoverflow.com/a/18695701/5386374 )
    template<typename T> struct ret_type;

    template<typename RT, typename... Ts> struct ret_type<RT (*)(Ts...)> {
        using type = RT;
    };
} // namespace ReturnTypeCapture

// ...

std::string f1() {
    return std::string("Nyahaha.");
}

int f2() {
    return -42;
}

char f3() {
    return '&';
}

template<typename R, typename F> auto rtCaller2(R r, F f) -> typename R::type {
    return f();
}

template<typename F> void rtCaller(F f) {
    auto a = rtCaller2(ReturnTypeCapture::ret_type<F>{}, f);
    std::cout << a << " (type: " << typeid(a).name() << ")" << std::endl;
}

// ...

rtCaller(f1); // Output (with gcc): "Nyahaha. (type: Ss)"
rtCaller(f2); // Output (with gcc): "-42 (type: i)"
rtCaller(f3); // Output (with gcc): "& (type: c)"
```

Furthermore, we can simplify it even more, and check the return type *without* a separate wrapper.

```
template<typename F> auto rtCaller2(F f) -> typename ReturnTypeCapture::ret_type<F>::type {
    return f();
}

template<typename F> void rtCaller(F f) {
    auto a = rtCaller2(f);
    std::cout << a << " (type: " << typeid(a).name() << ")" << std::endl;
}

// ...

rtCaller(f1); // Output (with gcc): "Nyahaha. (type: Ss)"
rtCaller(f2); // Output (with gcc): "-42 (type: i)"
rtCaller(f3); // Output (with gcc): "& (type: c)"
// Same output.
```

Having that sticking off the end there is *really* ugly, though, so can't we do better than that?  The answer is... yes!  We can use an alias declaration to make a `typedef`, leaving a cleaner name.  And thus, the final result here is:

```
namespace ReturnTypeCapture {
    // Credit goes to Angew ( https://stackoverflow.com/a/18695701/5386374 )
    template<typename T> struct ret_type;

    template<typename RT, typename... Ts> struct ret_type<RT (*)(Ts...)> {
        using type = RT;
    };
} // namespace ReturnTypeCapture
template <typename F> using RChecker = typename ReturnTypeCapture::ret_type<F>::type;

std::string f1() { return std::string("Nyahaha."); }
int f2() { return -42; }
char f3() { return '&'; }


template<typename F> auto rtCaller2(F f) -> RChecker<F> {
    return f();
}

template<typename F> void rtCaller(F f) {
    auto a = rtCaller2(f);
    std::cout << a << " (type: " << typeid(a).name() << ")" << std::endl;
}
```

So now, if we combine parameter checking & return type deduction...

```
// Parameter match checking.
namespace ParameterCheck {
    template<typename T, typename... Ts> struct parameter_match : public std::false_type {};

    // Declare (GetColor, int16_t*) valid.
    template<> struct parameter_match<int (*)(int16_t*), int16_t*> : public std::true_type {};

    // Declare (GetFile, FilePath&) valid.
    template<> struct parameter_match<int (*)(FilePath&), FilePath> : public std::true_type {};

    // Declare (WriteDocument, const FilePath&, const char*, bool) valid.
    template<> struct parameter_match<int (*)(const FilePath&, const char*, bool), FilePath, const char*, bool> : public std::true_type {};

    // Declare everything without a parameter list valid.
    template<typename T> struct parameter_match<T (*)()> : public std::true_type { };
} // namespace ParameterCheck

// Discount return type deduction:
namespace ReturnTypeCapture {
    // Credit goes to Angew ( https://stackoverflow.com/a/18695701/5386374 )
    template<typename T> struct ret_type;

    template<typename RT, typename... Ts> struct ret_type<RT (*)(Ts...)> {
        using type = RT;
    };
} // namespace ReturnTypeCapture

// Alias declarations:
template<typename F, typename... Ts> using PChecker = ParameterCheck::parameter_match<F, Ts...>;
template<typename F> using RChecker = typename ReturnTypeCapture::ret_type<F>::type;

// ---------------

int GetColor(int16_t* color);
int GetFile(FilePath& file);
int WriteDocument(const FilePath& file, const char* fileFormatName, bool askForParams);

std::string f1() { return std::string("Nyahaha."); }
int f2() { return -42; }
char f3() { return '&'; }

// ---------------
// Calling function (C++11):

// The actual calling function.
template<typename Func, typename... Ts> auto caller2(std::true_type x, Func f, Ts... args) -> RChecker<Func> {
    std::cout << "Now calling... ";
    return f(args...);
}

// Parameter mismatch overload.
template<typename Func, typename... Ts> auto caller2(std::false_type x, Func f, Ts... args) -> RChecker<Func> {
    std::cout << "Parameter list mismatch." << std::endl;
    return static_cast<RChecker<Func> >(0); // Just to make sure we don't break stuff.
}

// Wrapper to check for parameter mismatch.
template<typename Func, typename... Ts> auto caller(Func f, Ts... args) -> RChecker<Func> {
    // return caller2(ParameterCheck::parameter_match<Func, Ts...>{}, f, args...);
    return caller2(PChecker<Func, Ts...>{}, f, args...);
}

// ---------------
// Calling function (C++14):

// The actual calling function.
template<typename Func, typename... Ts> auto caller2(std::true_type x, Func f, Ts... args) {
    std::cout << "Now calling... ";
    return f(args...);
}

// Parameter mismatch overload.
template<typename Func, typename... Ts> auto caller2(std::false_type x, Func f, Ts... args) {
    std::cout << "Parameter list mismatch." << std::endl;
}

// Wrapper to check for parameter mismatch.
template<typename Func, typename... Ts> auto caller(Func f, Ts... args) {
    // return caller2(ParameterCheck::parameter_match<Func, Ts...>{}, f, args...);
    return caller2(PChecker<Func, Ts...>{}, f, args...);
}
```

You should be able to get the functionality you want out of this, I believe.  The only caveat is that if you do it this way, you need to explicitly declare functions valid in `ParameterCheck`, by making a template specialisation for the function & its parameter list, derived from `std::true_type` instead of `std::false_type`.  I'm not sure if there's a way to get true dynamic parameter list checking, but it's a start.

[I'm not sure if you can just overload `caller()` or if you explicitly need to use `caller2()` as well.  All my attempts to overload `caller()` via template parameters ended up crashing the compiler; for some reason, it chose `template<typename Func, typename... Ts> void caller(Func f, Ts... args)` as a better match for `caller(std::true_type, f, args...)` than `template<typename Func, typename... Ts> caller(std::true_type x, Func f, Ts... args)`, even with the latter listed before the former, and tried to recursively expand it until it ran out of memory.  (Tested on two online gcc compilers: [Ideone](http://ideone.com/), and [TutorialsPoint's compiler](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_cpp_online.php) (with `-std=c++11`).  I'm not sure if this is a gcc problem, or if I was a bit off about how template matching works.  Unfortunately, the [online VStudio compiler](http://webcompiler.cloudapp.net/) is down for maintenance, and the only version of VS I have available to me offline at the moment doesn't support variadic templates, so I can't check which is the case.)  Unless someone says otherwise, or says how to fix that particular issue, it's probably best to just use `caller()` as a wrapper & `caller2()` to do the heavy lifting.]

---

Examples of pretty much everything here that would be relevant to your problem: [here](http://ideone.com/yVMEQ9)

---

Also, note that you can't easily pull individual arguments from a parameter pack.  You can use recursion to strip arguments off the front a few at a time, you can use them to initialise member variables in a constructor's initialisation list, you can check how many arguments are in the pack, you can specialise it (as we did for `parameter_match`), & you can pass the whole pack to a function that takes the right number of arguments, but I believe that's it at the moment.  This can make them a bit more awkward than C-style `varargs` at times, despite being more efficient.  However, if your `ExecuteMethod()`'s argument list consists of a function and *its* argument list, and nothing else, this isn't an issue.  As long as the parameter match succeeds, we can just give the entire pack to the passed function, no questions asked.  On that note, we can rewrite `ExecuteMethod()` into something like...

```
// Not sure what cx is, leaving it alone.
// Assuming you wanted ExecuteMethod to take parameters in the order (cx, function, function_parameter_list)...

// Parameter list match.
template<typename M, typename... Parameters>
static bool ExecuteMethodWorker(std::true_type x, JSContext* cx, M method, Parameters... params)
{
    auto r = method(params...);
    // ...
}

// Parameter list mismatch.
template<typename M, typename... Parameters>
static bool ExecuteMethodWorker(std::false_type x, JSContext* cx, M method, Parameters... params)
{
    // Handle parameter type mismatch here.
    // Omit if not necessary, though it's likely better to use it to log errors, terminate, throw an exception, or something.
}

// Caller.
template<typename M, typename... Parameters>
static bool ExecuteMethod(JSContext* cx, M method, Parameters... params)
{
    return ExecuteMethodWorker(PChecker<M, Parameters...>{}, cx, method, params...);
}
```

Make sure to either prototype or define the worker functions before `ExecuteMethod()`, so the compiler can resolve the call properly.

(Apologies for any typoes I may have missed anywhere in there, I'm a bit tired.)

---

Edit: I've located the problem with passing references to a template.  It seems that using templates to determine types does indeed remove reference-ness in and of itself, hence notation like `template<typename T> void func(T&)` for functions that take a reference.  Sadly, I'm not yet sure how to fix this issue.  I *did*, however, come up with a new version of `PChecker` that dynamically reflects types for any function that *doesn't* use reference types.  So far, however, you still need to add references manually, and non-const references probably won't work properly for now.

```
namespace ParameterCheck {
    namespace ParamGetter {
        // Based on an answer from GManNickG ( https://stackoverflow.com/a/4693493/5386374 )

        // Turn the type list into a single type we can use with std::is_same.
        template<typename... Ts> struct variadic_typedef { };

        // Generic case, to catch passed parameter types list.
        template<typename... Ts> struct variadic_wrapper {
            using type = variadic_typedef<Ts...>;
        };

        // Special case to catch void parameter types list.
        template<> struct variadic_wrapper<> {
            using type = variadic_typedef<void>;
        };

        // Generic case to isolate parameter list from function signature.
        template<typename RT, typename... Ts> struct variadic_wrapper<RT (*)(Ts...)> {
            using type = variadic_typedef<Ts...>;
        };

        // Special case to isolate void parameter from function signature.
        template<typename RT> struct variadic_wrapper<RT (*)()> {
            using type = variadic_typedef<void>;
        };
    } // namespace ParamGetter

    template<typename... Ts> using PGetter = typename ParamGetter::variadic_wrapper<Ts...>::type;

    // Declare class template.
    template<typename... Ts> struct parameter_match;

    // Actual class.  Becomes either std::true_type or std::false_type.
    template<typename F, typename... Ts> struct parameter_match<F, Ts...> : public std::integral_constant<bool, std::is_same<PGetter<F>, PGetter<Ts...> >{}> {};

    // Put specialisations for functions with const references here.
} // namespace ParameterCheck

template<typename F, typename... Ts> using PChecker = ParameterCheck::parameter_match<F, Ts...>;
```

See [here](http://ideone.com/s99POm).

--

Edit 2: Okay, can't figure out how to grab the passed function's parameter list and use it directly.  It *might* be possible using tuples, perhaps using the rest of GManNickG's code (the `convert_in_tuple` struct), but I haven't looked into them, and don't really know how to grab the entire type list from a tuple at the same time, or if it's even possible.  [If anyone else knows how to fix the reference problem, feel free to comment.]

If you're only using references to minimise passing overhead, and not to actually change data, you should be fine.  If your code uses reference parameters to modify the data that the parameter is pointing to, however, I'm not sure how to help you.  Sorry.

--

Edit 3: It looks like `RChecker` might not be as necessary for C++11 function forwarding, we can apparently use `decltype([function call])` for that.  So...

```
// caller2(), using decltype.  Valid, as args... is a valid parameter list for f.
template<typename Func, typename... Ts> auto caller2(std::true_type x, Func f, Ts... args) -> decltype(f(args...)) {
    std::cout << "Now calling... ";
    return f(args...);
}

// Parameter mismatch overload.
// decltype(f(args...)) would be problematic, since args... isn't a valid parameter list for f.
template<typename Func, typename... Ts> auto caller2(std::false_type x, Func f, Ts... args) -> RChecker<Func> {
    std::cout << "Parameter list mismatch." << std::endl;
    return static_cast<RChecker<Func> >(0); // Make sure we don't break stuff.
}

// Wrapper to check for parameter mismatch.
// decltype(caller2(PChecker<Func, Ts...>{}, f, args...)) is valid, but would be more verbose than RChecker<Func>.
template<typename Func, typename... Ts> auto caller(Func f, Ts... args) -> RChecker<Func> {
    // return caller2(ParameterCheck::parameter_match<Func, Ts...>{}, f, args...);
    return caller2(PChecker<Func, Ts...>{}, f, args...);
}
```

However, as noted, `decltype` can have issues when it can't find a function call that matches what it's passed exactly.  So, for any case where the parameter mismatch version of `caller2()` is called, trying to use `decltype(f(args...))` to determine return type would likely cause issues.  *However*, I'm not sure if `decltype(auto)`, introduced in C++14, would have that issue.

Also, in C++14-compatible compilers, it's apparently better to use `decltype(auto)` than just `auto` for automatic return type determination; `auto` doesn't preserve `const`-ness, `volatile`-ness, or reference-ness, while `decltype(auto)` does.  It can be used either as a trailing return type, or as a normal return type.

```
// caller2(), using decltype(auto).
template<typename Func, typename... Ts> decltype(auto) caller2(std::true_type x, Func f, Ts... args) {
    std::cout << "Now calling... ";
    return f(args...);
}
```

`decltype(auto)` can also be used when declaring variables.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24109800/5386374) for more information.

---

Edit 4: I believe I may have found a potential solution that preserves the passed function's parameter list properly, using [functors](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/functors-function-objects-in-c++.html).  However, it may or may not create unwanted overhead, I'm not sure.

```
// Default functor.
template<typename... Ts>
struct Executor { };

// General case.
template<typename M, typename ReturnType, typename... Params>
struct Executor<M, ReturnType (*)(Params...)> {
    public:
        // Parameter match:
        bool operator()(M method, Params... params) {
            ReturnType r = method(params...);
            // ...
        }

        // Parameter mismatch:
        template<typename... Invalid_Params>
        bool operator()(M method, Invalid_Params... ts) {
            // Handle parameter type mismatch here.
        }
};

// Special case to catch void return type.
template<typename M, typename... Params>
struct Executor<M, void (*)(Params...)> {
    public:
        // Parameter match:
        bool operator()(M method, Params... params) {
            method(params...);
            // ...
        }

        // Parameter mismatch:
        template<typename... Invalid_Params>
        bool operator()(M method, Invalid_Params... ts) {
            // Handle parameter type mismatch here.
        }
};


// Variadic function-like macro to automatically create, use, and destroy functor.
// Uncomment whichever one is appropriate for the compiler used.
//  (The difference being that Visual C++ automatically removes the trailing comma if the
//   macro has zero variadic arguments, while GCC needs a hint in the form of "##" to tell
//   it to do so.)
// Also note that the "do { ... } while (false)" structure is used to swallow the trailing
//  semicolon, so it doesn't inadvertently break anything; most compilers will optimise it
//  out, leaving just the code inside.
//   (Source: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Swallowing-the-Semicolon.html )
// MSVC:
// #define ExecuteMethod(C, M, ...)                   \
//     do {                                           \
//         Executor<decltype(&M), decltype(&M)> temp; \
//         C = temp(M, __VA_ARGS__);                  \
//     } while (false)
// GCC:
#define ExecuteMethod(C, M, ...)                   \
    do {                                           \
        Executor<decltype(&M), decltype(&M)> temp; \
        C = temp(M, ##__VA_ARGS__);                \
    } while (false)
```

In this case, you can use it as:

```
ExecuteMethod(return_value_holder, function_name, function_parameter_list);
```

Which expands to...

```
do {
    Executor<decltype(&function_name), decltype(&function_name)> temp;
    return_value_holder = temp(function_name, function_parameter_list);
} while (false);
```

With this, there's no need to manually go through the parameter pack and make sure each one matches the passed function's parameters.  As the passed function's parameter list is quite literally built into Executor as `Params...`, we can simply overload the function call operator based on whether the arguments it was passed match `Params...` or not.  If the parameters match the function, it calls the `Parmas...` overload; if they don't, it calls the `Invalid_Params...` overload.  A bit more awkward than true reflection, IMO, but it seems to match everything properly.

Note that:

1. I'm not sure whether using functors liberally can cause any performance or memory use overhead.  I'm... not all that familiar with them at the moment.
2. I don't know if it's possible to combine the general case and the "`void` return type" special case into a single functor.  The compiler complained when I tried, but I'm not sure if it's because it isn't possible or because I was doing it wrong.
3. Considering #2, when modifying this version of `ExecuteMethod()`'s parameters, you have to modify it and both versions of `Executor` to match.

Like so, where `JSContext* cx` is added to the parameter list:

```
template<typename M, typename ReturnType, typename... Params>
struct Executor<M, ReturnType (*)(Params...)> {
    public:
        bool operator()(JSContext* cx, M method, Params... params);
};

template<typename M, typename... Params>
struct Executor<M, void (*)(Params...)> {
    public:
        bool operator()(JSContext* cx, M method, Params... params);
};

#define ExecuteMethod(C, cx, M, ...)               \
    do {                                           \
        Executor<decltype(&M), decltype(&M)> temp; \
        C = temp(cx, M, ##__VA_ARGS__);            \
    } while (false)
```

This may be the solution, but it requires further testing to see if it has any negative impacts on performance.  At the very least, it'll make sure const-ness and reference-ness is preserved by `ExecuteMethod()`, and it's a lot cleaner than my old ideas.

See [here](http://ideone.com/DwC4zm).

There are further improvements that can be made, however.  As I'm out of space, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36412247/5386374).

---

Notes:

1. `int16_t` (a.k.a. `std::int16_t`) is in the header `<cstdint>`.
2. `std::true_type` and `std::false_type` are in the header `<type_traits>`.

Comment: Don't be sorry, it is a delicate matter. I might ask too much :). You've put a lot of work here and I need some time to assimilate it. Thank you, I'll come back when I finish the study.

Comment: @mike Okay, basically...   The 1st part (`SomeClass`) is a general example of using `<type_traits>` to overload functions based on whether they meet a condition or not.  The 2nd part (`ParameterCheck::parameter_match<F, Ts...>`) is how we can use that to make sure that a function's argument list consists of a function pointer, and the arguments that that function takes, by defining specific cases that are valid and marking everything else invalid.

Comment: The 3rd part (`auto` and `ReturnTypeCapture::ret_type<F>`) is how to determine variable type and function return type automatically; for the latter, you can just use `auto` with any C++14-compatible compiler, but you need something like `ReturnTypeCapture::ret_type` for one that's only C++11-compatible.  The 4th part (`RChecker`) is how we can make a templated typedef to shorten a long name (such as `ReturnTypeCapture::ret_type<F>::type` into `Rchecker`).

Comment: The 5th part (`RChecker` and `PChecker`) is tying it all together, with both C++11 and C++14 examples of automatically deducing return type from a passed function's return type.  The 6th part (parameter pack discussion, your `ExecuteMethod()`, after the first Ideone link) is a look at the limitations of variadic template parameter packs, and an idea for how you can use those ideas with your functions.  We don't need to compare arguments to the passed function's argument list one at a time, we can just do that in one operation.

Comment: The 7th part ("Edit:" section) is a dynamic version of `PChecker` that compresses `ExecuteMethod`'s parameter list (not counting the passed function or anything before it) and the passed function's parameter list into single types, so we can compare them dynamically, without having to manually specify what is and isn't valid.  [It works for everything except reference types, which is why you still need to specify them manually.]

Comment: The 8th part ("Edit 2:" section) was where I was saying that I'm not sure how to use the passed function's argument list directly in `ExecuteMethod()`'s argument list.  (Such as, for any given function `M` that fits the model `RT (*)(M_Ts...)`, write `ExecuteMethod()`'s parameter list as `(JSContext* cx, M method, M_Ts... params)`.)  If we could do that, it would _probably_ solve the reference issue, but I'm not sure.  The 9th part ("Edit 3:" section, just added) is just a note on `decltype`.

Comment: As it stands now, the problem is that the template can't determine when you want to pass a reference, instead of passing a parameter by value.  It can be fixed by appending a `&` after the template parameter (such as, for any `typename T`, writing it as `T&` in the function argument list), but if we do that to a variadic template's parameter pack, it seems to apply it to every parameter, and thus they don't match the passed function's argument list anymore.

Comment: I just don't know how to make it properly deduce which ones should and shouldn't be references, unfortunately, nor do I know how to get the types of every element in a tuple at the same time (since there doesn't seem to be a way to assign multiple types to a single identifier outside of the variadic template parameter pack itself, my best idea for how to use a tuple to hold all the types, then expand its type list whenever we need it (such as `caller2(F f, PList<F>)` expanding PList to F's parameter list), but I don't know how to get more than one type out of a tuple at the same time).

Comment: @mike Okay, I've found one more thing that might work: using a functor for `ExecuteMethod()`.  See the "Edit 4" section near the bottom of the post.  I'm not sure if it would have any negative impact on performance, though, I'm not very familiar with the specifics of how functors work.  It might be best to look for another solution elsewhere first, but at least this'll make sure that `Params... params` matches the passed function's parameter list exactly, preserving const-ness & reference-ness.  Might be a hassle to keep maintained, though.

Comment: Wait... I just saw your Edit 2 there.  You're explicitly required to use `unsigned argc, JS::Value *vp` as your functions' parameter list?  That's... not what I thought the case was at all, I thought you were just using that because of familiarity with a different language.  If you explicitly _need_ to compare `Params...` to the contents of your array, you're probably better off with what Straw1239 suggested.

Comment: Hi, believe it or not, I've finished studying your great post. You've confirmed me that some clever macros are necessary. I've done some similar ExecuteMethod(s) too, but for specific number of params, so far.

Comment: ... And yes, SpiderMonkey needs some specific functions signatures, that's why I have used templates in the first place. It works like this: you write some javascript code like object.method(a, b, c). This is interpreted by the virtual machine and is materialized in an internal function call, one of my wrappers, specially written for that object and method.

Comment: This wrapper has the above mentioned signature and is used to pass the parameters (a, b, c here). They are javascript objects, wrappers for real objects. The internal code of the method needs to unwrap them by getting their data, if exist, to pass to the "real" function - the one to be called by ExecuteMethod(s). After that, the objects returned by the "real" function (either return value, either other out params) are wrapped back and sent accordingly in the variable pack of received parameters (JS::Value *vp). This needs a really clever code, if possible...

Comment: Still unclear to me is if it is possible to pass a heterogeneous set of params, by value and by reference at the same time, as a variadic pack...

Comment: @mike I'm not familiar with contexts yet, so I don't think I'll be able to help much with that.  I'm self-taught, and haven't gotten to them yet.  And... what do you mean by "by value and by reference at the same time"?  If you're asking whether it's possible to mix pass-by-value and pass-by-reference in the same signature, yes.  If you're asking whether it's possible to pass the same parameter both by value and by reference at the same time, as a single argument, no.  If you're asking whether items can be passed by reference properly when using a functor, yes.

Comment: The functor's `operator()` parameter list is an exact match to the passed function's parameter list, along with the function itself.  This includes reference-ness.

Comment: I'm asking if I could have "a, &b, c" for "..." and works, for example.

Comment: @mike Yes, you can.  Ran out of space in that large post, so see http://stackoverflow.com/a/36412247/5386374 for both a couple improvements that can be made, and an example that does just that.

Comment: Well, in my case, it's more complicated. I need to match the template types in the variadic pack to the elements in the JS::Value *vp array by iterating through the types variadic pack, in order to call some static methods on these types for each element. I've no idea how to write a template to iterate through the types. i.e. through the `typename... Params` of `template<typename M, typename... Params>`, because each type of params is a template of type of each item of the vp array.

Comment: @mike Ah.  Hmm... I'm not sure how to do that either, actually.  I don't know if it's possible to iterate over elements of a parameter pack without using recursion to strip them off the front one or more at a time, and I don't know how you'd be able to use that to match the stripped element to an element in `vp` and then return the matched element's value.  Sorry.  Hopefully someone else can give you a more useful answer.

Comment: For a start, I would use recursion (as it is the only way) and use somehow the vp array to create objects of type in the variadic types pack. Could be possible to pass the index of the type and the element of vp by the same index at once, if possible, and return sort of an array of objects. It is pretty difficult to understand for me how that recursion works.

Comment: @mike Hmm... I was thinking about the upcoming C++17 changes when I mentioned that I wasn't sure if there was a way to iterate over elements without recursion (I haven't looked at them yet, not sure if there's anything better suited to this particular problem), and I don't know how you would recursively map the parameter pack's types to members of `vp` to obtain the parameters for the passed function.  Perhaps you could make a helper function that obtains each argument by recursively stripping elements off the front of the pack until it reaches that element, or store elements in a tuple and

Comment: retrieve them by type, or something, I honestly don't have any idea how to use the parameter pack's types in conjunction with the context to create the passed function's parameter list.  Or, if that's not what you mean, I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: (I was thinking of a helper function something like `template<typename T, typename... Ts> T argument_obtainer(T t, Ts... ts, size_t position) { return (position == 0 ? getFromContext<T>() : argument_obtainer(ts..., --position)); }` , where `getFromContext()` somehow obtains the correct element of the specified type.  I'm not sure if it would work as intended, however, nor how you could call the passed function with a parameter list that automatically expands to calling `argument_obtainer()` for each parameter.)

Comment: There's probably a more efficient way than this, but for the life of me, I can't think of it.  I found out about most of the ideas in my post while trying to come up with the answer, but I don't even know _where_ to start looking for this.  Sorry I can't be any more helpful. >.<

Comment: I think here is a solution, but somehow I can't use it properly in order to match a collection of data, the parameters, (indexable as args[i]), against a variadic pack of types: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14261183/how-to-make-generic-computations-over-heterogeneous-argument-packs-of-a-variadic?rq=1. I have opened a clearer question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36461452/c-function-caller-wrapper-using-variadic-pack-types-expansion, I don't think is fully redundant, but I feel I should join them in the end.

Comment: @mike I hope you find a solution that does what you want it to, I'm out of ideas.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to tell from your description, but this is my closest interpretation to what you asked:

```
auto foo(int) { cout << "foo int" << endl; }
auto foo(float) { cout << "foo float" << endl; }
//... other foo overloads...

template <class T>
auto uber_function(T t)
{
    foo(t);
}

template <class T, class... Args>
auto uber_function(T t, Args... args)
{
    foo(t);
    uber_function(args...);
}

auto main() -> int
{
    uber_function(3, 2.4f);
    return 0;
}
```

Of course this can be improved to take references, to make forwarding. This is just for you to have a starting point. As you weren't more clear, I can't give a more specific answer.